# Why am i getting object address when i try to print each key using (from keySet())?

Tags: java, hashmap

I am using a foreach loop to print all the keys stored in my HashMap and their values using map.get(key) but iam getting object address when i try to retrieve those keys. Where am i going wrong?

```
String s="abba";
HashMap<String,Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<s.length();++i)
{
  for(int j=i+1;j<=s.length();++j)
    {
      char sub[]=s.substring(i,j).toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(sub);
      String s1=sub.toString();
      if(!map.containsKey(s1))
     map.put(s1,1);
      else
    map.put(s1,map.get(s1)+1); //Here also iam getting null value with map.get(s1)
     }
}

for(String keyList:map.keySet())
{
    System.out.println(keyList+" "+map.get(keyList));
}
```

If the key is repeated then the value should be incremented by 1 but it remains 1.

Comment: Use `new String(sub)` instead of `sub.toString()`.

Comment: "but iam getting object address" What do you mean by object address?

Comment: Use String.valueOf(sub) instead of sub.toString();

Comment: Yeah!! I got it. It was because of sub.toString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.valueOf(sub)` instead of `sub.toString()`;
`sub.toString()` will return same address everytime.